# Install from RPM, then files change. How can I see the differences?

Tags: security, rpm, rhel

This is a RedHat Enterprise 5.5 system. I ran a verification check against an RPM, and it looks like two files have changed:

```
# rpm --verify shadow-utils 
S.5....T  c /etc/default/useradd
S.5....T  c /etc/login.defs
```

I have access to the RPM which originally installed these files. Can diff these changed files against the version which is stored in the RPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the contents of the RPM to the disk (and not into / but some other directory). I use mc for this, where you can enter a rpm-file like a directory and extract the files you need. To extract the whole RPM into the current directory you might do something like

```
rpm2cpio yourrpm.rpm | cpio -idmv
```